# jQuery regex match not appending to a div class

Tags: html, jquery, regex

I have a ul class with links that I'm trying append to a specific div class if the regex matches but for some reason my regex matches just fine but it's not appending it to the div class. My goal is to move the the ul classes that match the regex and append it to the test3 class. Here is my html code along with my jquery

**HTML Code**

```
<ul class="links">
<li>
<a class="links active" href="#test">Link </a>
</li>
</ul>

<ul class="links">
<li>
<a class="links active" href="#test">Link </a>
</li>
</ul>

<ul class="links">
<li>
<a class="links active" href="#test">Link </a>
</li>
</ul>

<ul class="links">
<li>
<a class="links active" href="#test">Link </a>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="test3"></div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var test = test.match(/(<ul class="links">[\s\S]*?<a class.*?\[ABC\d\d\d\d\d\]<\/a>\s*<\/li>\s*<\/ul>)/g);
     return test.appendTo('.test3');
});
```

**After Regex match it will look like:**

```
<div class="test3">
<ul class="links">
<li>
<a class="links active" href="#test"></a>
<li>
</ul>

<ul class="links">
<li>
<a class="links active" href="#test"></a>
<li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a few issues here. Firstly your fiddle doesn't include a reference to jQuery. Even adding that there's an error because `test` isn't defined anywhere. The last issue is one of the approach - never, **ever**, use regex to parse HTML. If you can edit the question to describe the goal we can show you the correct approach to your issue

Comment: Thank you Rory for your reply. I went ahead and edited the question. My goal is to basically move the ul classes that match the given regex to the test3 class. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dude12go8/vbnokc3p/12/)

Comment: Thanks for updating I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your logic.

- It's incredibly bad practice to parse HTML using Regex. Use a DOM parser instead, and work with the elements there. As you've already included jQuery in the page you can use that.
- You need to loop through every `ul` element to determine if the `a` contained within it matches the Regex and move it, not clone the HTML content.
- `match()` returns an array of strings, not jQuery objects which you can call `append()` on.
- `test` is undefined.
- You need to run the Regex against the text content of the `a` within each `ul`, not the `ul` as a whole.
- The `test()` method of the Regex would be a better fit for your purpose.
- Use `\d{N}` in the Regex instead of repeating `\d`

With all that said, try the below example. Note that I made the Regex case-insensitive. You can easily amend this if it doesn't suit your needs.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $ul = $('ul.links').each((i, el) => {
    let $el = $(el);
    if (/\[ABC\d{5}\]$/.test($el.find('a').text().trim(), 'i')) {
      $el.appendTo('.test3');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.test3 {
  border: 2px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="links">
  <li><a class="links active" href="#test">Link [DEF56789]</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="links">
  <li><a class="links active" href="#test">Link [ABC12345]</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="links">
  <li><a class="links active" href="#test">Link [DEF12345]</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="links">
  <li><a class="links active" href="#test">Link [ABC56789]</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="test3"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I noticed that this not working in IE 11. Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: Thats because IE11 doesn't support ES6, so you'll need to replace the arrow functions with anonymous functions. A better idea would be to stop using IE11 at all  though :)

Comment: I changed it to: `jQuery(function($) {
  let $ul = $('ul.links').each(function(i, el) {
    let $el = $(el);
    if (/\[ABC\d{5}\]$/.test($el.find('a').text().trim(), 'i')) {
      $el.appendTo('.test3');
    }
  });
});` but I am still getting the same result.

Comment: You'll also need to change let to var

Comment: got thanks! works now. Really appreciate it.